# Array.contains(where:) to return Array item that returned true

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, contains

In Swift, say we have a draggable UIButton that can be dropped on a number of Views. What is the swiftest way to gain reference to said View?

```
let Array: [UIViews] = [View1, View2, View3, View4, View5, View6]

func oneFingerSwipe(_ gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let pointInView = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)

    switch(gesture.state){
            case .changed:
                Button.center = CGPoint(x: pointInView.x, y: pointInView.y)
            case .ended:
                if Array.contains(where: { $0.frame.contains(pointInView)}) {
                    // do something to said View($0) through either Array[index] or reference to the View($0)
                }
```

//INSTEAD of long winded

```
                if View1.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View1
                } else if View2.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View2
                } else if View3.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View3
                } else if View4.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View4
                } else if View5.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View5
                } else if View6.frame.contains(pointInView) {
                    //do work to View6
                }
            default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [`UIView().hitTest(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't name your variable `Array`... `Array` is already a name of a type, which you can now only access by its qualified name, `Swift.Array`. The Swift convention is to use lowerCamelCase for variable names. Besides, in `let Array: [UIViews] = ...`, i can SEE that `Array` is an array, it says it right there! Name it something useful that actually tells me what this array is holding, e.g. `tappableSubviews`

Comment: @Alexander thanks but this is just for theory and generalization so that when someone else searches this question they can easily relate to their situation.

Comment: yeah, neither "theory" nor "generalization" justify shadowing standard library types with local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to filter the array of views and take the first matching one using [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) function:

```
if let targetView = Array.first(where: {$0.frame.contains(pointInView)} ) {
    ...
}
```